# How can I see my previous ads on Backpage?

Tags: backpage

I wonder how I can see my previous postings on Backpage.

My account main page is pretty much empty:

[image]

On Craiglist I can see my postings in my main page:

[image]

Comment: Did you already take look to the [Backpage help](http://www.backpage.com/classifieds/Help)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was just a temporary issue: I can see my previous ads now.

if anyone else look for them:

[image]

[image]